# HelloTabWidget - ArtistsActivity cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: android, android-intent

Having trouble with the HelloTabWidget [http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html].

It all seems to work ok with no errors, except for hellotabwidget.java that comes up with a [ArtistsActivity cannot be resolved to a type] error for the below line:

```
        // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this,ArtistsActivity.class); // <<< ERROR HERE
    Log.v(TAG,"---artist activity is called---");
    // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("artists").setIndicator("Artists",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_artists)).setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

Any ideas why I'm getting this error?

EDIT:
The code with the errors is hellotabwidgetactivity.java, the default java file...  There are three other files AlbumsActivity.java ArtistsActivity.java and SongsActivity.java... All of these additional files are mentioned in the manifest xml as below

```
    <activity android:name=".AlbumsActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
     </activity>
```

I would print more of the code, but it is too fiddily to do that on here.

Comment: @coder_For_Life22 I've added some details.  But that code was in the default java file.  Respond if you need further info.

Answer (score 0):

It is not able to find ArtistsActivity class. Make sure this class is created in the appropriate package.